# How to add multiple scores to user in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have built a quiz game where when a player finishes their score is submitted to mongodb as an object for e.g:

```
{
    _id: "b7db3e12161567"
    name: "james"
    score: 5
}
```

Now what I want to do is to create multiple quizzes, not just one.  I've created multiple quizzes which all have a unique name i.e `quiz1`, `quiz2`, `quiz3` etc.

I want to use this `quizId` and give each player a score for the specific quiz they play instead of just one singular score. I was thinking something like:

```
{
    _id: "b7db3e12161567"
    name: "james",
    quiz1: 5,
    quiz2: 6
}
```

Here is my current code for the version which just the single score:

```
try {
    const { _id, name, score, quizId } = req.body;

    const users = await mongodb.getDb()
    .db('database')
    .collection('users')
    .updateOne(
        { _id }, 
        { $set: { _id, name }, $max: { score } },
        { upsert: true }
    );

    res.json(users);
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error('Cannot add user score');
}
```

How would I implement what I suggested with mongo? And or would there be a better way to implement what I suggested?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an update with pipeline query like:

```
.updateOne(
  { _id, name }
  [
    {$set: {
      quiz1: {$max: ["$quiz1", 3]},
      quiz2: {$max: ["$quiz1", 7]}
    }}
  ],
  { upsert: true }
)
```

Which works like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sq8XUK5AArG)

You can create it dynamically of course with something like:

```
const setPart = {}
for (const quiz_name of Object.keys(quizes)) {
  setPart[quiz_name] = `{$max: ["$${quiz_name}", ${quizes[quiz_name]}]}`
}
const users = await mongodb.getDb()
    .db('database')
    .collection('users')
    .updateOne(
        { _id }, 
        { $set: setPart  },
        { upsert: true }
    );
```